# Select and update on the rows in a table by using joins multiple table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I am trying to update 1.2 million rows in a table that had data inserted kind of incorrectly via legacy application. I am not very good at writing efficient SQL queries as I am experiencing these sort of larger set of data for the first time.

I have written query as below and it's taking a very long time to run this query. I have commented out my update logic in the statement.

```
SELECT T1.Old_id,
       T1. Report_id,
       T2.New_id /* update a set file_id = T2.new_id*/
FROM
  (SELECT A.File_id AS Old_id,
          A.Id AS Report_id,
          A.User_id AS USER
   FROM A
   INNER JOIN B ON A.Id = B.A_id
   INNER JOIN C ON B.Id = C. B_id
   INNER JOIN D ON C.Id = D.C_id
   INNER JOIN E ON D.Id = E.D_id
   WHERE E.Name = 'student_report') AS T1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT Max(C.Report_id) AS New_id,
          C.Created_by AS User_id
   FROM C
   INNER JOIN D ON C.Id = D.C_id
   INNER JOIN E ON D.Id = E.D_id
   WHERE E.Name = 'teacher_report'
   GROUP BY C.Created_by) ON T1.User_id = T2.User_id /* where a.id = T1.report_id*/
```

I need to update the file_id in table a by the report_id of c. With a small set of data, the select query works fine and gives the result as intended. But on the server where it has 1.2 million rows, it takes extremely long time.

Is there a way we could put those two sub-queries into one and make it work for 'update' as well? Because, update also fails as it has 'group by' on the second sub-query.

Comment: Have you try isung [INDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)?

Comment: Yes, I have indexes on the key fields. But, I am not allowed to add more indexes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is using `Subquery` in join condition.

Second problem,when same resultset is to be use multiple time then you should put common resultset in `CTE` or `#temp` table.

```
    create table #temp(B_id int,cTeport_id int,cUserID int,EName varchar(100))

   insert into #temp
   select B_id,C.Report_id,C.Created_by,E.Name
   INNER JOIN C ON B.Id = C. B_id
   INNER JOIN D ON C.Id = D.C_id
   INNER JOIN E ON D.Id = E.D_id
    WHERE E.Name in( 'teacher_report','student_report')

    ;With CTE as
    (
        SELECT Max(C.Report_id) AS New_id,
          C.Created_by AS User_id
   FROM #temp c
     WHERE c.Name = 'teacher_report'
     GROUP BY C.Created_by
    )

    SELECT T1.Old_id,
       T1. Report_id,
       T2.New_id /* update a set file_id = T2.new_id*/
FROM
  (SELECT A.File_id AS Old_id,
          A.Id AS Report_id,
          A.User_id AS USER
   FROM A
   INNER JOIN B ON A.Id = B.A_id
   INNER JOIN #temp t ON B.Id = t. B_id
   WHERE t.Name = 'student_report'
   and exists(select 1 from cte t1 T1.User_id = T.User_id)
```

My script is not Tested so you can fix any minor bug if any.

In `Temp table` carefully define all columns which is require for this query along with their `datatype`.

Answer (score 0):

Please analyze the Query cost by using Execution Plan. Check the table which is making delay then check proper Indexing used for that particular table or not.

[image]

Comment: Sub-queries run fine when they are run individually. But when I join them they run extremely slow.
Regarding indexes, I have them on keys but not on other fields such as file_id. I am not allowed to add keys there.